# How to use image from internet in PyGame without saving it on disk?

Tags: image, python-3.x, pygame, urllib

I tried this:

```
import pygame
import urllib.request

page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://s.gjcdn.net/img/logo-small-3.png")
image = page.read()

pygame_image = pygame.image.frombuffer(image, (196, 25), "RGB") #(196, 25) are checked on image original
```

But when I run it I get `ValueError: Buffer length does not equal format and resolution size`

Is there any way to do this (**without** saving file to the disk), or maybe I did something wrong in my code?

I would also like to know how to know size of image (because I mostly can't know size of image)?

Comment: technically, you're downloading the image EVERY time you run this code. just because you're not saving it to disk doesn't magically make it a "not-a-download".

Comment: @Marc B I meant not saving to the disk.

Comment: Try using `image = cStringIO.StringIO(page.read())`.

Comment: @martineau I use Python 3 and I don't have `cStringIO` in my library, is it 3rd part library (if it is where can I download it?) and if it's only in Python 2 what can I use for instead of `cStringIO`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, your question wasn't tagged Python 3. No `cStringIO` isn't a third-party library, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914472/stringio-in-python3/18284900#18284900).

Comment: Then I got this error `TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes` (I used io.StringIO)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in RGBA format? The image does contain alpha values after all.
If that doesn't help, then there is this question. It's dealing with sockets, but it may be relevant.
[Pygame not working with sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622019/pygame-not-working-with-sockets)

Comment: I tried RGBA format but it's same error, also that question/answer isn't very helpful.

Comment: I just did a quick search, and it seems that you can't use frombuffer with a compressed png image. The function expects raw pixel data. [link](http://archives.seul.org/pygame/users/Dec-2005/msg00158.html)

Answer (score 0):

`image.frombuffer` is for creating an image from data already loaded into memory as an image buffer. What you want is `image.load`, which takes an image file and turns it INTO an image buffer. You should just be able to pass it your `page` since that's a file-like object already.

Comment: I got error `pygame.error: Can't seek in this data source` when I use pygame.image.load().